# Python Faceplusplus API

Tags: python, string, unicode, buffer, typeerror

I am trying to upload an instance of an image to the faceplusplus api.  Everything works if I upload an Image from a drive or a URL, but when I use an instance of an image I get an error.   Here is my code below.

```
import image
import requests
import StringIO
from facepp import API, File


url = "http://blogs.reuters.com/great-debate/files/2013/07/obama-best.jpg"
response = requests.get(url)
img = Image.open(StringIO(response.content))

result = api.detection.detect(img = File(img), mode = 'normal')
```

Due to the use of Google App Engine, I have to create an instance of an image from a url.  What method should I use to upload the image to the Faceplusplus API?

Here is the error I get:
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, instance found

Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**step 1 :**

update facepp.py

```
class File(object):
"""an object representing a local file"""
path = None
content = None
# add a parameter content
def __init__(self, path,content=None):
    self.path = path
    if content :
        self.content = content
    else :
        self._get_content()
```

**step2 :**

```
url = "http://blogs.reuters.com/great-debate/files/2013/07/obama-best.jpg"
response = requests.get(url)
result = api.detection.detect(img=File('{custom image name}',response.content), mode = 'normal')
```

print result